# How to solve unrecognized arguments error?

Tags: ipython, argparse, python-3.6

The problem is that I can not get through the first step of running the simplest command. When I write this code

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.parse_args()
```

an then i get this error

> usage: **main**.py [-h]
>   **main**.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f
>   C:\Users\Saeid\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-301e1312-128e-4c4d-9ae8-
>   035b05a69a59.json

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

> C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-
>   packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2889: UserWarning: To exit: use
>   'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
>   warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

Comment: Why are you even using `argparse`?  What commandline arguments do you want to parse?  Also how are you running this script?  From shell?  from within a running Ipython session?  WIth the Ipython `run`?  or something else.  You haven't provided enough context.

Answer (score 2):

As funky-future pointed out, you should not be using an IPython notebook with `argparse`. To test how it works, let's assume a file named `test.py` with the following content:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("echo")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.echo)
```

Now in your terminal (cmd or PowerShell) you go to the directory with the `test.py` file and type:

```
python test.py 123
```

The output should be:

```
123
```

[Source](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `argparse` module is used to parse command line arguments. Hence, it doesn't make much sense to do so in an IPython or Jupyter notebook. The error propably stems from the fact that the notebook was invoked with an `-f` option.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, but my problem is how i should implement this script. obviously i'm new in python and i dont know how i should use argparse with ipython, if you could provide me with a procedure, i would be appreciated. ( i use ipython in anaconda and its running on windows7)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid that error message, you can do

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.parse_args([])
```